# Cassandra/Kafka Java driver, see JVM exit 143 when connection lost

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka

I'm writing a Java client to connect to Cassandra.
When I deliberately kill Cassandra server, the client's JVM immediately exits with 143.

It's the same result when doing the same experiment on Apache kafka. 
I quickly grep and see neither the Java driver nor Netty calls System.exit.

Is killing the JVM done somewhere in the Cassandra or the Kafka Java driver? If so, is there a particular reason why?(JDBC driver throws a SQLException in that situation which might be better.)

If JVM shutdown is unavoidable and I want my service keep running, I would isolate the cassandra/kafka clients in another JVM, e.g. using Akka remote. Is it a good idea?

P.S. I'm using `cassandra-driver-core:3.0.0-rc1` and `kafka-clients:0.9.0.0`

**[EDIT]**
I knew `addShutdownHook`, but that's not what I'm looking for, because JVM is going to die anyway. My application connects to Cassandra and provides other services. I don't want the application dies because the connection to Cassandra lost.

**[EDIT]**
Also I'm curious about two more things than adding a hook:

1. Why the JVM aborts. Is it coming from Cassandra java driver?
2. Is a good idea to put the Cassandra-client logic in another JVM like, for example, Akka remote.

Comment: what do you think `C*` means? because it is not a standard representation of anything

Comment: it is also unclear what you are doing and what you expect to be happening, you reference servers and drivers and clients all mixed together in the same context.

Comment: In Cassandra community, C* refers to Cassandra, but I'll edit my post to write it in full name.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't think it's a duplicate question. Please see my edit. And if you agree please remove the duplicate mark.

Comment: I agree, this doesn't seem like a duplicate.  His client should not get killed when killing the server.

Comment: Do you have any daemon threads?

Comment: @Richard I did a little test and got the same result regardless whether there's a daemon thread.